# How to use an element of json data instead of field in the widget to display full list?

Tags: php, json, yii, yii1.x

I saved some data in json format into my database in one field called json. I used widget in order to display full list of products.

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'page-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'json',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I decoded field (called `json`) which contains json data. And I am going to use a value of decoded `json(p_1 element of decoded json (json["p_1"]))` in the widget instead of whole field (called `json`).

(Because fields(called `json`) contains a lot of data and I need only one data). How can I use p_1 instead of field(called `json`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a php expression as the value to be displayed. `$data` represents the data model for the row.

```
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
        'name' => 'json',
        'value' => '$data->json["p_1"]'
    ),
```

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail

Comment: It is not working. I used to retieve  json data using following code $json["p_1"]  ( Here $json=CJSON::decode($model->json);). when I inserted $ sign before  json( 'value' => '$data->$json["p_1"]'), it did not work

Comment: It looks like you aren't assigning the decoded json correctly. Does the code in your question show json in the `json` column?